# Excel - Formula will not skip rows after spreading

Tags: vba, excel

could you advise me, if is possible to spread / copy formula, but it won't skip rows? E.g.

I have sheet INPUT, where I want to copy this formula: `=REPLACE(A6,34,999,REPLACE(CSV!D2,1,7,""))` everywhere, if it starts by ":86"

[image]

I've macro for it, but if the formula is spreaded like that, it will skip rows on the sheet CSV.

```
For Each C In rng
        If Left(C.Value, 3) = ":86" Then
        C.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=REPLACE(RC[-1],34,999,REPLACE(CSV!R[-4]C[2],1,7,""""))"
        End If
    Next C
```

But I would need to keep going row by row on the sheet CSV. So if I copy the formula into B9, the formula will be - `=REPLACE(A9,34,999,REPLACE(CSV!D3,1,7,""))` or B14 - `=REPLACE(A14,34,999,REPLACE(CSV!D4,1,7,""))`, etc.

Many thanks for your advices!

Comment: Could you explain what Patten you use to increment the reference to ripped in the CSV sheet?

Comment: Just added the part of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a string var representing your base formula and substitute in the dynamic values as you find matches.

```
Dim f As String, a As Long, c As Long

f = "=REPLACE(A%a%, 34, 999, REPLACE(CSV!D%c%, 1, 7, TEXT(,)))"
c = 2

With Worksheets("input")
    For a = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If Left(.Cells(a, "A").Value2, 3) = ":86" Then
            .Cells(a, "B").Formula = Replace(Replace(f, "%a%", a), "%c%", c)
            c = c + 1
        End If
    Next a
End With
```

The replacements are similar in concept to a mail merge.

Answer (score 2):

You can use If to insert the preferred formula, similar to:

```
Dim i as Long, lr as Long, x as Long, y as Long
lr = cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row
for i = 2 to lr
    x = LEN(cells(i,1))
    y = LEN(REPLACE(cells(i,1),":86",""))
    if x - y > 0 then cells(i,2).value = "=REPLACE(RC[-1],34,999,REPLACE(CSV!R[-4]C[2],1,7,""""))"
next i
```

Comment: Works for me as well. Thanks a lot!